# gcc optimization skips initializing allocated memory

Tags: c, gcc, strict-aliasing

Using gcc 4.9.2 20150304 64 bit I bumped into this apparently strange behavior:

```
double doit() {
    double *ptr = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    ptr[0] = 3.14;
    return (double)((uintptr_t) ptr);
}
```

In the code I'm allocating a `double` on the heap, initializing it and then returning another `double` initialized with the address of the first one converted to an `intptr_t`. This, with optimization `-O2`, generates in 32-bit mode the following assembly code:

```
sub    $0x28,%esp
push   $0x8                   ;; 8 bytes requested
call   8048300 <malloc@plt>   ;; malloc 'em
movl   $0x0,0x14(%esp)        ;; store zeros in upper 32bits
mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)        ;; store address in lower 32bits
fildll 0x10(%esp)             ;; convert a long long to double
add    $0x2c,%esp
ret
```

and amazingly enough the initialization of the allocated `double` is completely gone.

When generating code with `-O0` everything works as expected and the relevant code is instead:

```
push   %ebp
mov    %esp,%ebp
sub    $0x28,%esp
sub    $0xc,%esp
push   $0x8                    ;; 8 bytes requested
call   8048300 <malloc@plt>    ;; malloc 'em
add    $0x10,%esp
mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
fldl   0x8048578               ;; load 3.14 constant
fstpl  (%eax)                  ;; store in allocated memory
mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
mov    %eax,-0x28(%ebp)        ;; store address in low 32 bits
movl   $0x0,-0x24(%ebp)        ;; store 0 in high 32 bits
fildll -0x28(%ebp)             ;; convert the long-long to a double
fstpl  -0x20(%ebp)
fldl   -0x20(%ebp)
leave  
ret
```

## Question

Did I do anything invalid (I'm thinking specifically to aliasing rules, even if it seems to me that skipping the initialization has no justification) or is this just a gcc bug?

Note that the very same problem is present when compiling to 64 bit code (formally `intptr_t` in 64-bit mode is 8 bytes and therefore ad `double` could not be able to represent it exactly... this doesn't happen however because on x86-64 only 48 of the 64 bits of addresses are used and a `double` can represent all those values exactly).

Comment: You probably mean `Value res = *ptr;`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: what do you mean?

Comment: You may want to compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O2`

Comment: The compiler is correct in optimizing like it does.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Can you provide an explanation of why gcc is allowed to assume I won't be able to access the memory after decoding the `double`?

Comment: I forgot the details, but I remember having read something similar, probably on `gcc@gcc.gnu.org`; you might ask on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`; AFAIK `gcc` is optimizing correctly.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I didn't find find that discussion and filed a bug.

Comment: @6502, A stupid question: Does the same behaviour occur still if you compile the function in a module that contains only the `doit()` function?

Comment: @SergioFormiggini: yes, even compiling `doit` separately shows the problem

Comment: Your reply at my question (I think) demonstrates that is a bug! The compiler may not know what's the use the caller will do of the value `doit()` will return.

Comment: In C11 draft 6.5.4/4 (Cast Operators Contraints) I found: "*A pointer type shall not be converted to any floating type.*"

Comment: @alk: see simplified code. The pointer is not converted to a floating point type; `(double)` acts on an integer of type `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug... even with the simplified code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

double doit() {
    double *ptr = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    ptr[0] = 3.14;
    uintptr_t ip = (uintptr_t)ptr;
    return (double)ip;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    double v = doit();
    double *p = (double *)((intptr_t)v);
    printf("sizeof(uintptr_t) = %i\n", (int)sizeof(uintptr_t));
    printf("*p = %0.3f\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

when compiled with `-O2` doesn't initialize the memory.

The code works correctly returning directly an `intptr_t` (or an `unsigned long long`); but returning it after converting to a `double` doesn't work as `gcc` apparently assumes that in this case you won't be able to access the memory any more.

This is clearly false in 32-bit mode (where `intptr_t` is 4 bytes and `double` provides 53 bits of accuracy for integers) but also for 64-bit mode where while `uintptr_t` is indeed 8 bytes used values are 48 bits).

### EDIT

Not sure about this but the problem could be related to the "dead code elimination on tree" (`-ftree-dce`). When compiling in 32-bit mode enabling optimizations `-O2` but disabling this specific one with `-fno-tree-dce` the program output changes and is correct but the generated code **is not**.

More specifically the non-inlined version of `doit` contains no initialization code but the code generated in `main` inlines the call and the optimizer "knows" that the value of the memory is `3.14` and prints that directly in output.

### EDIT 2

Confirmed as a bug, already corrected in trunk.

Workaround until next release is `-fno-tree-pta`

Comment: The compiler is right. You don't use the `malloc`-ed memory. It could and perhaps should even skip the `malloc`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: What?

Comment: `ptr[0] = 3.14` is not using the malloced memory?

Comment: No, because the pointed zone is not escaping, you are casting it.

Comment: The interessing question now whould be whether gcc behave like this for everything but returning `u/intptr_t`. Does it work for example when directly returning `long long unsigned`?

Comment: @alk: with `unsinged long long` works, the problem seems `double`.

Answer (score 4):

Optimization is allowed to remove code in case of UB, but here it should not.

You have an unnecessary cast in `Value *ptr = (Value *)malloc(sizeof(Value));` but this should be harmless.

This line `res.d = (unsigned long long) ptr;` should better be `res.d = (intptr_t) ptr;`, because `intptr_t` is explictely allowed to receive pointers, and you can then set an integral value in a `double` variable : you can lose precision, but it should not be UB.

I cannot test it (because I have not a gcc 4.9) but if you have same problem with this :

```
#include <stdint.h>

...

Value doit() {
    Value *ptr = malloc(sizeof(Value));
    ptr[0].u = 7;
    Value res; res.d = (double) ((intptr_t) ptr);
    return res;
}
```

I would conclude to a gcc bug.

I could try to compile the *simplified* version of the code with clang version 3.4.1 on FreeBSD 10.1

`cc -O3 -S doit.c` gives (striped down to code part) :

```
doit:                                   # @doit
# BB#0:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-8, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $8, (%esp)
    calll   malloc
    movl    $1074339512, 4(%eax)    # imm = 0x40091EB8
    movl    $1374389535, (%eax)     # imm = 0x51EB851F
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    $0, 12(%esp)
    fildll  8(%esp)
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

It is not same compilation than what gcc does, but clang does the `3.14` initialization even at -O3 optimization level (dump hex for 3.14 is `0x40091eb851eb851f`)

---

After reading other comments and answers, I think that the real cause of the problem is that gcc *skips* the intermediate cast and reads `return (double)((uintptr_t) ptr);` as `return (double) ptr;` - well not exactly because it would then be a syntax error but still consideres there is UB since *at the end* a pointer value ends into a double variable. But if we decompose the line **with the intermediate cast** it should be read (IMHO) as :

```
register intptr_t intermediate = (intptr_t) ptr; // valid conversion
return (double) intermediate;  // valid conversion
```

Comment: The same happens using `(uintptr_t)` instead of `(unsigned long long)`.

Comment: @6502 : Clang **does** the 3.14 initialization even at -O3 level

Comment: Note that the bug is present even storing the intermediate result into an `intptr_t` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing strange here. You never read that `7` you written, instead you write result of `malloc` to a `double`:

```
Value *ptr = (Value*) malloc(sizeof(Value));
ptr[0].u = 7;
Value res; res.d = (uintptr_t) ptr; // ptr is a result of malloc
return res;  // ptr is lost here which probably makes 
             // GCC think that it is no longer accessible
             // so "7" is lost here too
```

And converting a pointer to a double will most likely lose a precision and thus making memory inaccessible (UB).

However, if you save your pointer to an integer (`.u`), GCC will treat that as aliased memory and keeps the initialization:

```
Value res; res.u = (uintptr_t) ptr; // Saving to .u, not .d
```

compiles to

```
0x0000000000400570 <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000400574 <+4>:     mov    $0x8,%edi
0x0000000000400579 <+9>:     callq  0x400460 <malloc@plt>
0x000000000040057e <+14>:    movq   $0x7,(%rax)
0x0000000000400585 <+21>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000400589 <+25>:    retq
```

**So the problem is that you saving pointer to a double.**

---

BTW, `(double)ptr` is a compile error, as standard requires:

> **6.5.4 Cast operators**
>
> [...]
>
> 4 A pointer type shall not be converted to any floating type. A floating type shall not be converted to any pointer type.

<sub>As of N1548 draft</sub>

Comment: It doesn't lose precision in 32-bit mode (a double provides 53 bits of accuracy and only 32 are used for pointers) but also it works on x86-64 (where of the 64 theoretical bits only 48 are used).

Comment: @6502: Conversion from pointer to a double is an UB. I doubt that GCC will calculate bits. Moreover, optimization is performed in GIMPLE, before any assembly code generated and double representation is known.

Comment: The code is not converting a pointer to a double, but a pointer to an `uintptr_t` and then the result (an integer) to a double.

Comment: @6502: it doesn't matter. The thing is that at the end of the `doit`, "number of alive pointers" = 0 and "number of alive addresses represented as integers" = 0, so for GCC there is no way to get information pointed by `ptr`

Comment: And that's not a bug in gcc reasoning? So if I say `sprintf` the numeric value of the `intptr_t` to a buffer and return that buffer gcc is allowed to skip the initialization too?

Comment: The code is not using aliasing at all and the code is not converting a pointer to a double. It is converting an **integer** to a double.  See simplified question code.

Comment: @6502: you use two conversions (pointer -> integer -> floating point), but it doesn't make your code more valid. The only non-pointer type that can represent pointer is _integer of enough size_

Comment: Once the pointer is an `intptr_t` I can store it wherever I want, memcpy'ing it around and sprintf-ing it to buffers. If I can rebuild later the same intptr_t value then casting back to a pointer must work.

Comment: @6502: But you didn't __store__ it anywere, you __convert__ it to double, there is the difference. And when you __store__ it to `u` (second example in my code), it works just fine.

Comment: I am converting an `uintptr_t` value; not a pointer: the type of `((uintptr_t)ptr)` is `uintptr_t`. That value (that is an integer of `uintptr_t` type and could have been coming from a multiplication) is then converted to a `double`. I don't see any violation of the standard in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

C is not assembler. C can invoke undefined behaviour where someone who views it as a high-level assembler cannot see why. As an example: Given two arrays int a [10] and int b [10], it is possible that by coincidence &a [10] == &b [0]. However, the following code

```
int a [10],  b [10];
int* p = &a [10];
if (p == &b [0]) *p = 0;
```

invokes undefined behaviour if p == &b [0]. Two pointers, p and &b [0], compare equal, and consist of the same bits, but behave differently. (If you disagree, look at "restrict" pointers where the whole point is that pointers comparing equal can behave differently).

The rules for conversion to uintptr_t are as follows: Every valid pointer can be converted to uintptr_t, and the result can be converted back to a pointer, giving the same pointer. The values are implementation defined, except that converting a null pointer to uintptr_t must give a zero, and converting a 0 to a pointer must give a null pointer. Nothing requires that the conversion should be simple, or should be what you think it should be.

The conversion to uintptr_t is implementation defined. If pointers in an architecture are restricted to n <= 62 bit, then it is entirely possible that the conversion goes like this: If p is a null pointer, convert it to zero. If p is not a null pointer, take the n bits, shift them to the left by (63 - n) bits, or the result with 0x8000 0000 0000 0001. The result  is guaranteed to not be convertible to double without loss. When the uintptr_t is converted to double, the result is such that it cannot be turned back into a valid pointer anymore.

As a result, if (double)(uintptr_t)p is the only value derived from p, then p cannot be reconstructed, the pointer p is lost, and an assignment to *p can be optimised away since *p cannot be read again.

Comment: When compiling in 32-bit mode `sizeof(uintptr_t)` is 4. Every possible bit combination of `uintptr_t` can be represented without loss of precision by a `double`. Fullstop. Yet `gcc` "optimizes" away the initialization **even when compiling in 32-bit mode**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe gcc is correct. You have not used the value and didn't return a pointer to it, so it's considering that the value has become unreachable.

You should have returned the pointer and cast to double elsewhere, or you need a union so that gcc knows that the pointer to the value still exists:

```
union CrazyDouble {
   double v;
   double *p;
};
```

Comment: The code converts the pointer to an unsigned integer that the standard guarantees is not losing information (7.20.1.4). That unsigned integer is then returned by the function after placing it in a double (that doesn't lose precision with integers of that size). If `gcc` thinks the memory is unreachable this is a `gcc` bug.

Comment: It's confirmed it was a bug in gcc 4.9, already corrected in trunk.